# .findByIdAndUpdate is not a function error - coming from controller where the model has been required?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a web application for my company to view a database of customers and their data using MongoDB, Mongoose, and Express. Our company resells used copiers/printers and also provides maintenance contracts for machines. I want to save each customer as a document, with machines as separate linked documents.

I have models, controllers, and routes set up for customers and machines. I am getting the following error when trying to delete a machine from it's customer:

> Customer.findByIdAndUpdate is not a function
> TypeError: Customer.findByIdAndUpdate is not a function at module.exports.deleteMachine (C:\controllers\machines.js:21:20) at C:\utils\catchAsync.js:3:9 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at next (C:\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13) at module.exports.getCustomer (C:\middleware.js:15:5) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

My code is as follows:

Controller for Machines:

```
const Customer = require('../models/customer');
const Machine = require('../models/machine');

module.exports.deleteMachine = async (req, res) => {
const { id, machineId } = req.params;
await Customer.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $pull: { machines: machineId } });
await Machine.findByIdAndDelete(machineId);
req.flash('success', 'Machine has been deleted');
res.redirect(`/customers/${id}`);
```

};

Route for Machines:

```
router.delete('/:machineId', getCustomer, catchAsync(machines.deleteMachine));
```

the "getCustomer" middleware is as follows - its only purpose is to ensure a valid customer is being requested and to set the "foundCustomer" to make my life easier elsewhere. I don't think it is the issue, but I'm including it just for clarity:

```
module.exports.getCustomer = async (req, res, next) => {
const { id } = req.params;
const customer = await Customer.findById(id).populate({ path: 'machines' });
if (!customer) {
    req.flash('error', 'Sorry, that customer cannot be found!');
    return res.redirect('/customers');
}
res.locals.foundCustomer = customer;
next();
```

};

The relevant routes have been set as follows in my app.js:

```
const customerRoutes = require('./routes/customers');
const machineRoutes = require('./routes/machines');
app.use('/customers', customerRoutes);
app.use('/customers/:id/machines', machineRoutes);
```

I haven't run into any issues with other machine routes, so I'm not sure why this one is throwing an error. This application is actually the second version that I've made, and the first version uses the *exact same* code, with no issue. So I'm super stumped.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Customer Model -

```
const customerSchema = new Schema({
customer: String,
customerID: String,
category: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['contracted', 'billable']
},
contacts: [contactSchema],
address: String,
city: String,
state: String,
zip: String,
county: String,
machines: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Machine'
    }
],
notes: [noteSchema]
});
```

Comment: Can you share the Customer model please ?

Comment: @ZahidÇakıcı I just added it to the bottom of the post for you, thanks!

Comment: @ZahidÇakıcı I figured it out - I explained in my answer, but I had required the model incorrectly in the Machine controller.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a dummy. I exported the Customer model as part of an array of exports like this:

```
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema);
module.exports = {
    Customer: Customer,
    Note: Note,
    Contact: Contact
};
```

When requiring the model in my Machine controller I had it formatted as:

```
const Customer = require('../models/customer');
```

To get it working correctly I needed to require it like this:

```
const { Customer } = require('../models/customer');
```

After making that change everything is working correctly, and I can move on with my life/application.